# How to view realtime data using Socket io in Node Js + Vue Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, socket.io

I'm a trying realtime data using socket.io but code isn't working. I'm inserting test data with connection API using postman.

How to view data in realtime without refresh in the browser?

**Realtime data in file `KritikList.vue`**

Below is my code.

Node Js Server:

```
io.on('connection', (client) => {
    console.log('user is connected with id: ' + client.id);
    client.on('SEND_MESSAGE', function(data) {
        io.emit('kirim_data', 'Get you right back...')
        console.log(data);
    });
    client.on('event', (data) => {
        console.log('data masuk', data);
    });
    client.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('disconnected');
    });
});
```

Controller Node Js Server:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    // Validate request
    if (!req.body.nama) {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: 'Nama tidak boleh kosong!',
        });
        return;
    }
    if (!req.body.alamat) {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: 'Alamat tidak boleh kosong!',
            status: 400,
        });
    } else if (!req.body.nohp) {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: 'No. Telp tidak boleh kosong!',
            status: 400,
        });
    } else if (!req.body.jenis_kritikan) {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: 'Jenis kritikan tidak boleh kosong!',
            status: 400,
        });
    } else if (!req.body.isi_kritikan) {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: 'Isi kritikan tidak boleh kosong!',
            status: 400,
        });
    } else {
        // Create a kritik
        const kritik = {
            nama: req.body.nama,
            alamat: req.body.alamat,
            nohp: req.body.nohp,
            jenis_kritikan: req.body.jenis_kritikan,
            isi_kritikan: req.body.isi_kritikan,
            is_accept: req.body.is_accept ? req.body.is_accept : false,

        };

        // Save kritik
        Kritik.create(kritik)
            .then((data) => {
                res.send({ message: 'Kritik anda telah tersampaikan', status: 200 });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                res.status(500).send({
                    message: err.message || 'Error saat simpan kritik.',
                });
            });
    }
};
```

Vue Js (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Go-Mas App || Kritik dan Saran</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./page.png">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="./socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">       </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var socket = io();
                socket.emit('kirim_data');
                socket.on('SEND_MESSAGE', function(msg) {
                    $("#app").append(msg + '<br /><br />');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Vue Js (App.vue)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="app">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-info">
        <router-link to="/" class="navbar-brand">Go-Mas App</router-link>
        <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link to="/kritik" class="nav-link">Kritik</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link to="/saran" class="nav-link">Saran</router-link>
          </li>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="container mt-3">
        <router-view />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
  sockets: {
    connect() {
      console.log("server connected");
    },

    disconnect() {
      console.log("server disconnected");
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.sockets.subscribe("SEND_MESSAGE", data => {
      this.$socket.emit("data");
      console.log(data);
    });
    this.sockets.unsubscribe("SEND_MESSAGE");
  },
  created() {
    this.sockets.subscribe("SEND_MESSAGE", data => {
      this.$socket.emit("data");
      console.log(data);
    });

    this.sockets.unsubscribe("SEND_MESSAGE");
  }
};
</script>

<style>
footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Vue Js (KritikList.vue)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h5 style="color:red">Cari data</h5>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Search by jenis kritikan"
            v-model="jenis_kritikan"
          />
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button
              class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
              type="button"
              @click="searchRowData"
            >
              Search
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h5 style="color:red">Kritik List</h5>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li
            class="list-group-item"
            :class="{ active: index == currentIndex }"
            v-for="(kritik, index) in kritiks"
            :key="index"
            @click="setActiveKritik(kritik, index)"
          >
            {{ kritik.nama }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div v-if="currentKritik">
          <h5 style="color:red">Kritik Detail</h5>
          <table width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:15px" width="20%"><strong>Nama </strong></td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>{{ currentKritik.nama }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:15px"><strong>Alamat </strong></td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>{{ currentKritik.alamat }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:15px"><strong>No. Telp </strong></td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>{{ currentKritik.nohp }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:15px"><strong>Jenis Kritikan </strong></td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>{{ currentKritik.jenis_kritikan }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:15px"><strong>Isi Kritikan </strong></td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>{{ currentKritik.isi_kritikan }}</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size:15px"><strong>Status </strong></td>
              <td>:</td>
              <td>
                <b
                  v-if="currentKritik.is_accept == 0"
                  class="badge badge-danger mr-2"
                  >Proses</b
                >
                <b v-else class="badge badge-primary mr-2">Selesai</b>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <br />

          <td v-if="currentKritik.is_accept"></td>

          <td v-else>
            <h5 style="color:red">Action</h5>
            <p class="mt-1"></p>
            <img
              width="50px"
              @click="updateStatus(true)"
              src="../../assets/okcek.png"
              alt="Proses Selesai"
            />
            &nbsp;<label style="font-size:14px">Proses Selesai</label>
            
          </td>
        </div>

        <div v-else>
          <br />
          <p>Klik untuk melihat detail...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
import KritikDataService from "../../services/KritikDataService";

export default {
  name: "data-connected",
  sockets: {
    connect() {
      console.log("server connected");
    },

    disconnect() {
      console.log("server disconnected");
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      kritiks: [],
      currentKritik: null,
      currentIndex: -1,
      jenis_kritikan: ""
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.sockets.subscribe("SEND_MESSAGE", data => {
      this.$socket.emit("data");
      console.log(data);
    });
    this.sockets.unsubscribe("SEND_MESSAGE");
  },
  created() {
    this.sockets.subscribe("SEND_MESSAGE", data => {
      this.$socket.emit("data");
      console.log(data);
    });

    this.sockets.unsubscribe("SEND_MESSAGE");
  },
  methods: {
    async retreiveKritik() {
      KritikDataService.getAll()
        .then(response => {
          this.kritiks = response.data;
          //   console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },

    refreshList() {
      this.retreiveKritik();
      this.currentKritik = null;
      this.currentIndex = -1;
    },

    setActiveKritik(kritik, index) {
      this.currentKritik = kritik;
      this.currentIndex = index;
    },

    searchRowData() {
      KritikDataService.findByJenisKritikan(this.jenis_kritikan)
        .then(response => {
          this.kritiks = response.data;
          // console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.retreiveKritik();
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.list {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px 12px 6px 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: How and where are you mounting vuejs? Also, You've 2 scripts tags in an SFC. You should import the socket library inside the script that wraps the vue component.

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero , view realtime data in file ```KritikList.vue```

Comment: Use vue-socket.io-extended and try debugging your socket connection

Comment: @kasvith i'm already using vue-socket.io

Comment: Did you test your server emitting the events correctly? you can use Firecamp to test sockets